# How do I show a MVC3 View in a tooltip of Html.ActionList?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted to show a tooltip window that displays "Details" view inside the tooltip window for the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id })
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you strictly want to use the native tooltip functionality, or would you be OK with using a lightweight javascript/jQuery to generate a tooltip-like effect?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a CSS approach for tooltips to be easy to implement. [Here](http://psacake.com/web/jl.asp) is an example. In your case, you would define the CSS to be:

```
.info {
    position:relative;
    z-index:24;
}

.info:hover {
    z-index:25;
}

.info span {
    display: none
}

.info:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:2em; left:2em; width:15em;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

If you also want to load your tooltips dynamically instead of all at once you would need to use some jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tooltip").bind("mouseenter", function () {
            $(this).unbind("mouseenter");
            var param = {id: "$(this).attr('itemid')"};
            $(this).load("/Details/Details", param);
        });
    });
```

Finally, you can use it as follows:

```
<span class="info">
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id })
    <span class="tooltip" itemid=item.Id></span>
</span>
```

Comment: itemid=item.Id says it should be in quote marks in span tag.  ive tried removing/adding quote marks.  this doesn't work. when i hover mouse over, i see a long black line only

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Could you try `itemid="@item.Id"`? Also, in your question you didn't include the code before the code block, but I'm assuming that `item` is already defined.

Comment: item is already defined.  all i see is a line when i hover mouse over the link.  "item.Id" is now there.  the url i want to go to is Details action with 5, are we sure that Details/Details,param is taking there in load function?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker You're seeing just a line since either the ajax call failed or it didn't return any data, you'll need to determine which first. If you add some text in the tooltip span and remove the jQuery code to load it should appear.

Comment: i added test in span and that appeared. i used url as www.google.com but no luck

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Just use this instead then. `<span class="tooltip">@Html.Action("Detail","Detail")</span>`

Comment: i think you meant @Html.ActionLink but no, it doesn't do anything. just shows hyperlink. are you sure it works on your machine at least?

Answer (score 1):

Almost every HTML element can have a [title attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3), and most browsers will display this attribute as a tool tip.

So you want to use one of the [ActionLink overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) that allows the setting of attribute values, something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id=item.Id}, new { title = "this is your tooltip" } )
```

Comment: To render a partial view in a tool tip, you'll need to render it in a hidden div, and show it when needed.  Take a look at http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/ for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

should be `var param = $(this).attr("param");` in Lester's javascript snippet